# How to lock inward opening window in place?

Tags: windows, lock

So I have a window that opens inwardly, however I can't figure out how to lock in place.
I can close the window just fine, but once open it won't stay in one spot, especially if it's windy outside.

I've added a couple of pictures and a video of how the window works on this
[image]

[image]

[image]

[Video.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAPcv.jpg)

Is there anyway I can lock it in place while the window is open?

PS: The window is made of metal, and it isn't a tilt and turn.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: this  might be too "rube goldberg" for some, but attach a weight on a string to the top edge of the window, a few inches from the opening side, so that it pulls the window shut by gravity. Now you have a window that always wants to self-close, which is easy enough to prop open with a stick or brick or whatever. It's also trivial to undo and let fully open when needed.

Comment: It wouldn't be pretty, but: screen door closer with  hold-open cam or latch? The one on my back door would work... Most windows of that sort which I have seen are operated by a casement mechanism and open outward.

Comment: Can you show a close up of the hinges?  Some are fiction fit and might just need to be tighten.  If just regular hinges then other fixes are needed, but @keshlam idea might be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that it collides with your screen and cant be opened all the way, I suggest you get a wedge or two, and lock it against the windowsill.
Soft wood works well, or even harder styrofoam from appliance packaging if you have any lying around.
Or anything of convenient height that you can jam under (except books).
If its windy outside, close your room door. The window should not move much if there is no possible air flow outside room, unless the room itself has an air duct.

Comment: Yep, a simple doorstop should do the trick if you just jam it under the frame. https://hw.menardc.com/main/items/media/NATIO063/ProductLarge/237891.jpg

Comment: He could pick up a book on window installation... that could be jammed under there to keep it open. Or even _Windows XP For Dummies!_ Any irony would just be a bonus.